# Is there a complete admin panel/interface for MQTT net or or any other private MQTT Servers/Broker?

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation, mqtt, iot

I'm making a simple automation system for someone and require a MQTT admin panel for server/broker. I want it such that the admin who runs the server, is able to see and change the password of the server or client. Also the admin would be able to see the all the topics and remove the subscription of of any client if they want. Admin will also be able to see all the messages sent and received.

I was currently looking at C# MQTTnet and mosquitto but all the servers require manipulation in config files through CLI(there own set of commands on CLI). Isnt there something I can use so that all is done in clean code with WPF form for interface? Is there a solution for this problem? I want a user interface for admin.

Also can a MQTT sever run by a novice user? who has no technical knowledge?

Any reply is much appreciated.

Comment: Asking for library suggestions/recommendations is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: So your requirements: 1) "able to see and change the password of the server or client"... there is no "server" -- there is a "Broker" and "Clients". The Broker has no password per se, and the clients can be defined in a password file for mosquitto. 2) "see all topics and remove the subscription of [of] any client if they want."  The subscriptions are maintains (for the most part) in memory....in order to have the ability to 'remove' subscriptions will take a custom MQTT Broker.

Comment: @JDAllen thanks for the reply...i wanted to know specifically about the user interface. I have seen HiveMQ interface but it only shows messages and clients with topics.I wanted something similar to that but with extra features such as i described. I wanted more admin features which u said need custom broker. I also wanted to know if we can transfer CLI commands to code.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a desktop GUI to manage the configuration of a MQTT broker, but you could use something like HiveMQ that bundles an administrative web portal with their package. If there is a web api then you could write API requests from your desktop application to interact with the administration portal.

See: https://www.hivemq.com/blog/restful-http-apis-with-hivemq/

This is just one of a very large number of possible approaches.

Comment: i like your knowledge and suggestion but i cannot use paid services as of now and hive trial only allows 25 clients. also im not getting into making personal api as i have less exp and time. Thanks for the answer.